# Cocos2d Chipmunk: Touch Shapes?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touch, shapes, chipmunk

Today i got a **cocos2d** question!

I got a few **shapes** and the **space-manager** set up in my .m file by using nodes:

```
- (CCNode*) createBlockAt:(cpVect)pt

                    width:(int)w
                   height:(int)h
                     mass:(int)mass
{
    cpShape *shape = [smgr addRectAt:pt mass:mass width:w height:h rotation:0];

    cpShapeNode *node = [cpShapeNode nodeWithShape:shape];
    node.color = ccc3(56+rand()%200, 56+rand()%200, 56+rand()%200);

    [self addChild:node];

    return node;
}

- (CCNode*) createCircleAt:(cpVect)pt
                     mass:(int)mass
                     radius:(int)radius
{
    cpShape *shape = [smgr addCircleAt:pt mass:mass radius:radius];
    cpShapeNode *node1 = [cpShapeNode nodeWithShape:shape];
    CCSprite *sprt = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"fire.png"];
    node1.color = ccc3(56+rand()%200, 56+rand()%200, 56+rand()%200);

    [self addChild:node1];

    return node1;
}
```

then i actually make the shapes, set up a background, alloc and start the space-manager in my init method:

```
- (id) init
{
    [super init];

    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"BGP.png"];
    background.position = ccp(240,160);
    [self addChild:background]; 

    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];

    //allocate our space manager
    smgr = [[SpaceManagerCocos2d alloc] init];
    smgr.constantDt = 1/55.0; 

    [smgr addWindowContainmentWithFriction:1.0 elasticity:1.0 inset:cpvzero];

    [self createBlockAt:cpv(160,50) width:50 height:100 mass:100];
    [self createBlockAt:cpv(320,50) width:50 height:100 mass:100];
    [self createBlockAt:cpv(240,110) width:210 height:20 mass:100];
    [self createCircleAt:cpv(240,140) mass:25 radius:20];

    [smgr start];

    return self;
}
```

**Now, i want a shape to be removed if it's touched. What is the best way to do that???**
I hope that somebody out there can help me :)

Edit:
**Plz somebody, start a bounty! Or i never get this answered :(**

-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this?

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    cpShape *shape = [smgr getShapeAt:point];
    if (shape) {
        [self removeChild:shape->data cleanup:YES];
        [smgr removeAndFreeShape:shape];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hello! I tried this out and got to warnings which made my game crash:    1st one: "Control reaches non-void function" (I removed it by adding return 0; at the end). 2nd one:'Game' may not respond to '-remove child'  How should i deal with the second warning??  Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the warnings, use removeChild:cleanup:.

Comment: OMG IT WORKS!!!! :D :D Thank You you helped me solve my Problem!!! But im not letting you go that easy XD I have one problem left: I have 2 rectangles on the screen that form an arch. On top of those two i have a third rectangle and on top of it, i have a ball. If i press one of two rectangles below, they disappear and smgr continues to work. But if i press the upper rectangle it disappears, but for some reason the ball doesn't fall down. Can you help me with this one??

Comment: removeAndFreeShape works? (fixed s/removeShape/removeAndFreeShape/)

Comment: Hmm. How about [smgr rehashStaticShapes] ? [Chipmunk document](http://files.slembcke.net/chipmunk/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/)

Comment: Nope it's not helping.. And btw the ball isn't a static shape.

Comment: EDIT: I made a few tests and noticed, that if a ball is on an object and you take that object away the ball isn't obeying the gravity anymore. I made an other test similar to the first one, but i put a shape 100 pixels above the ball. As that shape was falling i removed the shape underneath the ball. The ball floated in the air until the shape above it stroke it to the ground... This is getting really strange.